# What qualifies one as a Dai-Yokai?

Tags: inuyasha

In Inuyasha, there seems to be a higher class of Yokai, where Inuyasha's father belonged, called "Dai-Yokai" (or "Great Yokai").

What qualifies you (the average Yokai) to be a Dai-Yokai? Are you born like it? Do you earn the status somehow?

Comment: It's been a long time since I watched/read Inu-Yashi, but I was always under the impression it was just a name given to exceptionally strong demons, and is something you earn.

Comment: @Wipqozn: Does that make me one?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they need an even high class for you :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Inuyasha wiki](http://inuyasha.wikia.com/wiki/Daiy%C5%8Dkai) says the following about daiyōkai:

> Most daiyōkai have long lifespans, possibly even longer than those of
>   normal yōkai. They tend to remain calm in battle even if the situation
>   is dire or their life is threatened. Daiyōkai vary in shape and size,
>   just like normal yōkai. Some have, or are able to transform into,
>   human-like forms, such as the Inu no Taishō and Sesshōmaru. Others,
>   like Ryūkotsusei, are very large in size and don't at all resemble
>   humans. Though it is not clear whether this applies to all Daiyōkai,
>   it seems that some became feudal rulers over vast territories,
>   commanding lesser demons. They sometimes wage war against other yōkai
>   and humans alike.

About what qualifies one as such, is more controversial. It may be possible that it's both possible to be born like one, and to *become* one.

For example,  Inu no Taishō's son from an unnamed demoness, Sesshōmaru, is a daiyōkai, and even Inuyasha, while being half-human, possesses power beyond those of an ordinary yōkai, so "being born with it" is plausible.